# Raw SQL queries when using the Globalize gem with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, globalize

I am using the ruby gem Globalize to for translation purposes in a Ruby on Rails app. I have a model, `Region`, which I am translating the `name` column on. When using ActiveRecord to query the regions table, such as:

`Region.where(name: 'translated')`

The region record with the translated name `translated` is correctly returned. 
However, when I query with:

`Region.where('name like ?', 'translated')`

It returns an empty ActiveRecord_Relation. It seems that querying with SQL strings accesses database records directly without utilizing the Globalize gem.

How can I perform `like` queries that will retrieve translated records?

(I am working with Globalize 5.0.0 and Rails 4.2.8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I got to work for me was:

`Region.with_translations(I18n.locale).where('region_translations.name like ?', "translated")`

This joins the region_translations table on region_translations.region_id = regions.id, where I18n.locale = region_translations.locale

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
Region.includes(:translations).where('name like ?', 'translated')
```

This way you'll have access to the translation table from Globalize gem.